# Bash Script OSX not deleting files it finds

Tags: macos, bash, cron, find

I have this bash script here

```
#!/bin/bash
find /Users/ -name "*.mov" -o -name "*.flv" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.wmv" -o -name "*.mpeg" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.wmv" -o -name "*.f4v" -o -name "*.m4v" -o -name "*.mxf" -o -name "*.ts" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

It finds all the files that are older than 7 days, and that works fine, but when I want it to remove the result set that I found it doesn't delete any of the files. Is there something I'm doing wrong? This is on Mac OSX 10.6

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If you insert an `echo` between `-exec` and `rm`, does it list the commands you expect? If so -- what happens if you try running one of those commands directly yourself, without using `find`?

Comment: I run the find command and it lists all the files I expect to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, of `-exec rm -rf {}\;`, try the `-delete` option if it's available on your version of the `find` command. This will show an error message after each failed attempt to delete. That might give you more information what's going on.

```
$ find . -name "*.foo" -type f -mtime +7 -delete
find: -delete: unlink(./four.foo): Permission denied
find: -delete: unlink(./one.foo): Permission denied
find: -delete: unlink(./three.foo): Permission denied
find: -delete: unlink(./two.foo): Permission denied
```

Neither `find` is returning the actual exit code from the delete/rm command. You may want to do something like this:

```
find . -name ... -type f -mtime +7 | while read file
do
   if rm -fr $file
   then
      echo "Successfully deleted $file"
   else
      echo "Error deleting file: Exit code $?"
   fi
done
```

That might give you a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: THIS WORKED THANK YOU!!

`#!/bin/bash`
`find /Users/ -name "*.mov" -o -name "*.mpg" -o -name "*.flv" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.wmv" -o -name "*.mpeg" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.wmv" -o -name "*.f4v" -o -name "*.m4v" -o -name "*.mxf" -o -name "*.ts" -type f -mtime +7 | while read file`
`do
   if rm -fr $file
   then
      echo "Successfully deleted $file"
   else
      echo "Error deleting file: Exit code $?"
   fi
done`

Comment: Also to make this run on a schedule on OSX I couldn't use crontab I had to use this scheduler program called Lingon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run the command with sudo ? You may not have full access to all directories as a normal user.

Comment: How can I run sudo without entering the password?

Comment: Oh how I tested this was on a cron job I did sudo crontab -e -u root

Comment: @cohortq: Commands run from cron-jobs often behave differently from commands run at the command-line, because `cron` doesn't run your profile set-up scripts (to set the `$PATH` and so on). To see what's going on, you can add the command `exec >>/home/cohortq/whats-going-on.txt 2>&1` right before your `find` command. Then it will append any error information to `/home/cohortq/whats-going-on.txt`.

Comment: is your shell script executable ? Maybe it is not called at all ? Possibly you have to use the absolute path /usr/bin/find in your script that is called by cron. I'm not sure about /usr/bin being in crons search path.

Comment: I did a chmod u+x on the file that went into cron

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command is in /usr/bin, which isn't in the default PATH for cron jobs.  Either run it as `/usr/bin/find`, or set PATH at the beginning of your script.